# Why does Jeff Atwood have an 100% accept rate for answers if he himself recommends a 70%

Tags: discussion, accept-rate, jeff-atwood

In this blog post https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/new-question-asker-features/ Jeff Atwood explicitly mentions that he considers 70% a good accept answer rate:

> It is considered good manners to accept answers on your questions,
> eventually, but accepting answers is not required. I personally
> consider anything at 70% or over quite good, meaning you accept
> answers on 7 out of 10 questions that you ask. **There are certainly
> cases where you don’t get an answer you like, or the question is
> inherently unanswerable.**

Yet, his stackoverflow profile https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood reveals that he has an accept answer rate of 100% (You might have to click on one of his questions to see the accept answer rate)

EDIT:
In defense of myself. My rudimentary control of the English language actually allows me to understand the meaning of the word "over". However, that wasn't the focus of my question, rather: if Jeff states that not all questions are answerable, then why are all his questions answered? I'm not attacking him or throwing harsh accusations, I simply want to understand why Atwood is an exception to his own rule.

dmckee did give me the answer I was looking for.

Comment: 70% or over. 100% is over 70%. Therefore it is good according to his recommendation.

Comment: I imagine that (1) Jeff asks interesting and answerable questions and (2) they attract some attention above and beyond other question that meet the conditions of 1 *because it is Jeff asking*.

Comment: Jeff didn't ask all questions. That would be quite a feat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While he doesn't expect all questions to be answered well, it happens that all his questions got an answer that he was satisfied with. So he accepted those answers.

> If Jeff states that not all questions are answerable, then why are all his questions answered?

Because Jeff didn't ask all questions, just some that turned out to be answerable.

Of course also being well known on the site and asking good question makes more people look at them and improves the chances of getting good answers. This makes it more likely that he gets an answer worth accepting.

Answer (score 10):

He means that having an accepting rate that is at least 70% is quite good; he didn't say that you should not have an accepting rate higher than 70%.